# Accidentally closed a NetBeans tip window for the Swing GUI Builder

Tags: netbeans

I accidentally closed a UI element in NetBeans. It's the piece that says "Snap at the preferred distance from the container's right border" in this picture:

[image: GUI Builder]

I closed it with the X at the right of the tip text. Does anyone know how to get this back? I can't find it anywhere in toolbars, windows, or palette settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the main menu, select **Tools->Options**
2. Select the **Java** tab
3. Select the **GUI Builder** tab
4. Check **Show Assistant**
5. Click **OK**